# PubNub 4.2.5 Swift Objective-C method 'client:didReceiveStatus:' conflicts

Tags: swift2, pubnub

I'm using PubNub 4.2.5 on Swift IOS9.2 and received this conflect error message, any ideas how to resolve..thanks!

```
/Users/XXXX/xcode/XXXX/PubNub5/PubNub5/AppDelegate.swift:91:10: Objective-C method 'client:didReceiveStatus:' provided by method 'client(_:didReceiveStatus:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'client(_:didReceiveStatus:)' in protocol 'PNObjectEventListener'
```

Function

```
//Handle subscription status change.
    func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveStatus status: PNSubscribeStatus) {


    }
```

Comment: I changed PNSubscribeStatus to PNStatus..

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Subscribe iOS SDK Listener

The appropriate class should be `PNSubscribeStatus`.

The full subscribe code would like like the code below. See the [full docs for PubNub iOS Swift SDK v4.x subscribe API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/api-reference#subscribe).

```c
self.client?.subscribeToChannels(["my_channel1","my_channel2"], withPresence: false)
 
 
// Handle new message from one of channels on which client has been subscribed.
func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult!) {
 
    // Handle new message stored in message.data.message
    if message.data.actualChannel != nil {
 
        // Message has been received on channel group stored in
        // message.data.subscribedChannel
    }
    else {
 
        // Message has been received on channel stored in
        // message.data.subscribedChannel
    }
 
    print("Received message: \(message.data.message) on channel " +
                "\((message.data.actualChannel ?? message.data.subscribedChannel)!) at " +
                "\(message.data.timetoken)")
}
 
// Handle subscription status change.
func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveStatus status: PNSubscribeStatus!) {
 
    if status.category == .PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory {
 
        // This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost
    }
    else if status.category == .PNConnectedCategory {
 
        // Connect event. You can do stuff like publish, and know you'll get it.
        // Or just use the connected event to confirm you are subscribed for
        // UI / internal notifications, etc
    }
    else if status.category == .PNReconnectedCategory {
 
        // Happens as part of our regular operation. This event happens when
        // radio / connectivity is lost, then regained.
    }
    else if status.category == .PNDecryptionErrorCategory {
 
        // Handle messsage decryption error. Probably client configured to
        // encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.
    }
}
```